404 Not Found Error on Spring Liquibase PostgreSQL app
I keep receiving 404 Not Found error for my MVC app. Here are my code:
application.properties
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/demo1
spring.datasource.username=demo1
spring.datasource.password=demo1
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
server.port=5000

## Hibernate Properties
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
server.servlet.context-path=/api/

spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:db/changelog/master_changelog.xml
spring.liquibase.user=demo1
spring.liquibase.password=demo1

Person model
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    @Column(name="tax_id", nullable = false)
    private Long taxId;

    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
    private String lastName;

    private String fatherName;

    private String motherName;

    private LocalDate dob;

    public Person() {}

PersonRepository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> { }

PersonController
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class PersonController {

    private final PersonService personService;

    @Autowired
    private final PersonRepository personRepository;
    public PersonController(PersonService personService, PersonRepository personRepository) {
        this.personService = personService;
        this.personRepository = personRepository;
    }
    // get all persons
    @GetMapping("/persons")
    public List<Person> getAllPersons() {
        return this.personRepository.findAll();
    }

After running the Spring app, I have this 404 error:
{
    "timestamp": "2024-08-14T02:52:37.363+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "path": "/api/persons"
}

Even though when I go to Postgres DB, I can run:
SELECT * FROM person;
I containerize this application using Docker-compose. Here is my docker-compose.yml file:
version: '3.1'

services:
  app:
    image: 'docker-demo1-image:latest'
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: demo1
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/demo1
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=demo1
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=demo1
      - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update

  db:
    image: 'postgres:13.1-alpine'
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    container_name: db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=demo1
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=demo1


What is the full path that you're sending request to? Please share also the stacktrace

Try to remove server.servlet.context-path

Just a note: since you are using Liquibase you should keep hibernate.ddl-auto = validate to avoid conflicts between two different data migration tools (liquibase is preferrable for production)

If you set server.servlet.context-path=/api/ in your application.properties, use http://localhost:8080/api/api/persons to access the persons endpoint; otherwise, remove the context path configuration to use http://localhost:8080/api/persons, and restart your Spring Boot application to apply the changes.

Alright thanks y'all. the line server.servlet.context-path=/api or @RequestMapping("/api") are the problem as it duplicates the path of "/api".

As you have added server.servlet.context-path=/api/ in your application.properties, so, you need to call your endpoint like this - http://localhost:8080/api/api/persons.
Otherwise, remove this server.servlet.context-path=/api/ field and call the endpoint like this http://localhost:8080/api/persons.
It will work. See if this helps.

Error In Invalid URL
There are two way to solve this:
Remove server.servlet.context-path=/api/ this line from application.properties. When we add server.servlet.context-path=/api this line in application.properties then every API Start with this prefix.
OR 
Remove @RequestMapping("/api") from PersonController.

There is another problem in your controller.You use @Autowired incorrectly as you inject dependency by constructor there is no need of this annotation.
